# How to select any couple of digits except '00' using mysql regex subset syntax?

Tags: mysql, regex

I just found out that mysql doesn't support full regular expressions syntax. I have to select any couple of digits except of 00 (so, 11, 54, 02, are ok, but not 00).

Normally I would use a negative lookahead like this:

```
(?!00)[0-9]{2}
```

But in mysql it is not supported. So how could I do it?

Comment: have you tried `^`

Comment: Directly: `(0[1-9])|([1-9][0-9])`.

Comment: @Akina this works, you should put it as an answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct solution:

```
(0[1-9])|([1-9][0-9])
```

It is simple enough for do not look for shortening or another optimization, I think.